# Assert failed to capture the i from "i in range(x)"

Tags: python

I have such a function to find square root

```
In [71]: find_square_root??                         
Signature: find_square_root(x)
Docstring: <no docstring>
Source:   
def find_square_root(x):
    global count
    lo = 0
    hi = x

    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2 #

        #
        if lo == hi:
            count += 1
        if count > 3:
            return f"mid={mid}, lo={lo}, hi={hi}"

        if mid ** 2 == x:
            lo = mid
            return lo
        if mid ** 2 < x:
            lo = mid + 1
        if mid ** 2 > x:
            hi = mid

        print(f"mid={mid}, lo={lo}, hi={hi}")

    return lo - 1
File:      ~/<ipython-input-47-1f27a467513c>
Type:      function

In [72]: count            
Out[72]: 0
```

It works properly

```
In [81]: find_square_root(10)                       
mid=5, lo=0, hi=5
mid=2, lo=3, hi=5
mid=4, lo=3, hi=4
mid=3, lo=4, hi=4
Out[81]: 3
```

When come to test it edge cases,

```
for i in range(50, 50**50):
    res = find_square_root(i**i)
    assert res == i, f"res={res}, i={i}"
```

The AssertError

```
mid=2980232238769531249999999999999999999999990, lo=2980232238769531249999999999999999999999991, hi=2980232238769531250000000000000000000000063
mid=2980232238769531250000000000000000000000027, lo=2980232238769531249999999999999999999999991, hi=2980232238769531250000000000000000000000027
mid=2980232238769531250000000000000000000000009, lo=2980232238769531249999999999999999999999991, hi=2980232238769531250000000000000000000000009
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-d062083522e4> in <module>
      1 for i in range(50, 50**50):
      2     res = find_square_root(i**i)
----> 3     assert res == i, f"res={res}, i={i}"

AssertionError: res=2980232238769531250000000000000000000000000, i=50
```

It's very strange that res escalators up to 2980232238769531250000000000000000000000000 while i stay constant with 50.

Test i

```
In [86]: i                
Out[86]: 50

In [87]: res              
Out[87]: 2980232238769531250000000000000000000000000

In [88]: for i in range(3): 
    ...:     print(i) 
    ...:                  
0
1
2

In [89]: i                
Out[89]: 2
```

It still works properly.

What's the problem with the three lines of codes

```
In [90]: for i in range(50, 50**50): 
    ...:     res = find_square_root(i**i) 
    ...:     assert res == i, f"res={res}, i={i}"
```

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but `find_square_root` would sometimes return a string (`"mid={mid}, lo={lo}, hi={hi}"`) and you're comparing it to an `i` which is an `int`

Comment: The square root of `i**i` is not `i`. Why is that the test?

Comment: Yeah, there are several issues here, one being the fact that your function returns a string instead of an integer in one of its execution paths, and the other is that you are calling it with `i**` instead of `i*i` or `i**2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely want to change

```py
res = find_square_root(i**i)
```

to

```py
res = find_square_root(i**2)
```

Doing so, your code runs fine for me (although, since `50**50 = 8881784197001252323389053344726562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
, it will take more or less forever to run, so maybe you intended this to be `50**2` as well).